# How to create branch in master repository using git bash?

Tags: git, github, git-branch

I just wanted to create branch using git bash so anyone can give me guidance how to do it?

Comment: Question viewed 15K times and only 1 upvote.  Shame!  Have an upvote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To create a new branch:

```
> git branch newbranch
```

To create a new branch and switch to it:

```
> git checkout -b newbranch
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ git branch <branch name>      // To create a new branch
$ git checkout <branch name>    // To switch to a branch
$ git checkout -b <branch name> // Create and switch both
```

You can merge any branch (say xyz) with your current branch using

```
$ git merge xyz
```

Also You can delete a branch using

```
$ git branch -d <branch name>
```

And

```
$ git status
```

will tell you the branch which you are on (Current Branch)

Answer (score 0):

In your github fork, you need to keep your master branch clean, by clean I mean without any changes, like that you can create at any time a branch from your master. Each time, that you want to commit a bug or a feature, you need to create a branch for it, which will be a copy of your master branch.

When you do a pull request on a branch, you can continue to work on another branch and make another pull request on this other branch.

Before creating a new branch pull the changes from upstream, your master needs to be up to date.

Create the branch on your local machine and switch in this branch :

```
$ git checkout -b [name_of_your_new_branch]
```

Push the branch on github :

```
$ git push origin [name_of_your_new_branch]
```

When you want to commit something in your branch, be sure to be in your branch.

You can see all branches created by using :

```
$ git branch
```

Which will show :

- approval_messages
   master
   master_clean

Add a new remote for your branch :

```
 $ git remote add [name_of_your_remote]
```

Push changes from your commit into your branch :

```
 $ git push origin [name_of_your_remote]
```

Update your branch when the original branch from official repository has been updated :

```
 $ git fetch [name_of_your_remote]
```

Then you need to apply to merge changes, if your branch is derivated from develop you need to do :

```
 $ git merge [name_of_your_remote]/develop
```

Delete a branch on your local filesystem :

```
 $ git branch -d [name_of_your_new_branch]
```

To force the deletion of local branch on your filesystem :

```
 $ git branch -D [name_of_your_new_branch]
```

Delete the branch on github :

```
 $ git push origin :[name_of_your_new_branch]
```